# How could I have a specific page/subdomain point to a specific port/app?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a domain registered and the A record is pointing to my network.  I run a plex server and I have made it so I can access some tools remotely like Sonarr and Radarr.  Sonarr listens to a specific port and the gui will be accessed when using it.  So, domain.com:port will NAT you to the server running Sonarr and use the proper port to bring up the GUI.

I am wondering if there is a way I could simply type in sonarr.domain.com and get the same affect.

Answer (score 0):

"A record pointing to your network" makes no sense. It points to one or more IP's.

Said that, you can do what you want, having a reverse proxy in front of port 443 / 80 (deprecated), pointing to your backends, in different contexts.